# Session check redirect regardless correct login

Tags: php, session, authentication

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
        header('location:kursna_login.php');
    }
 ?>
```

Code always redirect me to kursna_login.php when the username and pass are correct in the login form. Is this the right declaration of the code?

Comment: enable `display_errors` to be sure that the session has started correctly, and be sure that `myusername` is really set

Comment: Are you setting $_SESSION['myusername'] ?

Comment: Im trying to update an old script to PHP 5 and I'm not very expirienced. When I remove the above code I login to the page correctly.
$_SESSION['myusername']= "myusername"; I guess this is setting the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are redirected to "kursna_login.php" so the session variable is not set , once you store the username in a session variable , for example let's suppose the username is coming from a form with a post method
you should save iy like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
 $_SESSION['myusername'] = $username;
```

and after this you have to checkk the session array eith a simple print_r like this

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

this would give you all the session variables setted in your app as key => value and then try to verify if the name is really setted in session global variiable or not .

Comment: Also reminding @Gorast to add session_start(); in the above action page

Comment: This is the correct answer. The file was lacking session_start(); before the registration lines. Thanks!